# Macbook Pro M1 stuck when opening the lid

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, trackpad

I am using Macbook Pro M1 13 inch-2020, 16GB RAM with Mac OS 12.5.1

Sometimes (not always), when I close the lid and open it again after a few hours, my Macbook is stuck.

It does not respond to anything. The trackpad does not work. The keyboard does not work. The cursor is moved to the top left of the screen and stop there.

I try to turn off by power button. It will go to Recovery screen, but the trackpad and keyboard don't work. The cursor still stop at the top left.

However, if I wait for a few hours, my Macbook might work again. And the situation occurs again after a few days.

Do you have any idea to fix the problem?

I tried Apple Dianogstic but it cannot find any issue.

The video: https://www.youtube.com/shorts/4tPhOxLmtn8

Comment: I have this same problem with a MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015). An SMC reset brings it back to life. But apparently there is nothing to be done on an M1 machine: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295

Comment: Yes, there is no SMC reset on Macbook M1.

Comment: I think the problem might be related to hibernation but I haven't investigated it or trying to disable it.

Comment: On M1 MacBook SMC reset seems to be done by shutting it down and waiting at least 30 seconds before restart.